# Fetch all data at once with pagination value in response using RxJava

Tags: android, rxjs, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to fetch pagination data all at once from a server with RxJava in Android App, but can't find the right solution.

This is response: `"has_next": true, "page": 1,"results": []`

What I already tried, but it obviously doesn't work.
My question is how to resubscribe every time to observable, until condition is met?

```
    fun getData(id: Int) {
    var hasNext = true
    var page = 1

    repository.getData(id, page)
        .repeatUntil { !hasNext }
        .map {
            hasNext = it.has_next
            page++
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnComplete {
            Timber.d("completed")
        }
        .subscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your code to the following, consider what repository is getting `Observable` type

```
    Boolean hasNext = true;
    repository.getData(id, page)
             .map(response -> {
                        hasNext  = response.has_next; 
                        return response;
    }).repeatUntil(()->!hasNext) // if it is true bucle stops 
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnComplete {
        Timber.d("completed")
    }
    .subscribe()
```